# Removing words that are all uppercase/lowercase. C++

Tags: c++, uppercase

The program reads a file and if the user adds an argument upper or lower, it will remove words that are either all uppercase or all lower case.

ie. "Hello World.... HELLO WORLD.... hello world"

'upper word' would output "Hello World.... .... hello world"
'lower word' would output "Hello World.... HELLO WORLD.... "

as of right now my code does take off the uppercase word, but assumes that it will break the loop only if the following character is not upper case.

Problem is, if its a string like "AABBaabb" the program should ignore it since there is a mix of upper and lower cases. Instead it will print "Baabb".

here's the function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < copyText.length(); i++)
{
   if (!ispunct(copyText[i]) || !isspace(copyText[i]))
   {
      while (isupper(copyText[i]) || isdigit(copyText[i]))
      {
         if (islower(copyText[i + 1]))
         {
            break;
         }
         else
            copyText.erase(copyText.begin() + i);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the sample input and the expected output.

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is just part of the program. There are other functions. copyText is a copy of the txt file (which is the input) and the output is a cout at the end. So it is not directly altering the txt file, just the temporary copyText.

Comment: `std::regex_replace(copyText, std::regex{"\\b[A-Z]*\\b"}, "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the condition in the first if statement will always evaluate to True. The ! (not) will be applied first, so the condition is essentially "if it's not punctuation or it's not a space." Since it can't be both punctuation and a space, this is always true. What I think you are trying to do is check whether the character is something other than a punctuation character or a space. You can do that like this

```
if(!(ispunct(copyText[i]) || isspace(copyText[i])))
```

or this.

```
if(!ispunct(copyText[i]) && !isspace(copyText[i]))
```

What your while loop is doing is, as long as copyText[i] is upper case or a digit, break if the VERY NEXT character - copyText[i + 1] -  is lower case, otherwise delete the current character. That's why it's not looking at the rest of the word before it starts deleting. Here is a modified version of your algorithm, which may or may not work (I haven't tested it), but it shows how I would start to modify your approach to make it functional.

```
for (int i = 0; i < copyText.length(); i++)
                {
                    while (!ispunct(copyText[i]) && !isspace(copyText[i]))
                    {
                        bool delChar = True;
                        for (int j = 1; i+j < copyText.length(); j++) {
                            if (ispunct(copyText[i+j]) || isspace(copyText[i+j])
                                break;
                            if (islower(copyText[i+j]))
                                delChar = False;
                            }
                        if (delChar)
                            copyText.erase(copyText.begin() + i);
                    }
                }
```

Now, if this works how I intended it to, it will fix your problem, but it still won't work in every case. For example, consider the word "aabbAABB". The algorithm will start reading at the first upper case letter, read to the end, and decide to delete the character. You will be left with only "aabb". You could add another inner for loop to read backwards from the current character to prevent this.

EDIT: changed if statement to while loop because I forgot about the effect of deleting a character on the indices of the other characters.

Comment: I get the logic of it, thanks, but I get a "subscript out of range" which I can hopefully figure out. And thanks for pointing out the || && problem.

Comment: Ah, that's probably because of the inner for loop. Trying to pull copyText[i+j] without checking that i+j < copyText.length(). I'll edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do following steps:

1. [std::regex_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) to collect words by pattern `\\w+`. [std::match_results](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) stores position & length of matches.
2. [std::all_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) + [std::isupper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper)/[std::islower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower) to detect uppercase/lowercase words.
3. [std::basic_string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) to delete words one-by-one (don't forget to update position offset after every deletion).

Comment: This option was also racing my mind. I wanted to count the upper case letters, then count how many letter there are, then compare, if they are the same delete that substring. Just couldn't figure out the syntax. thanks!